# Stack Exchange mobile app for iOS GUI bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, ios-app

Nothing major, just reporting.

There's a bug in the GUI of the Stack Exchange mobile app for iOS for which a submitted edit's title and tags will be displayed as removed if they haven't been touched at all:

[image: screenshot1]

As you can see, the title and the tags haven't been touched at all during the edit:

[image: screenshot2]

Here's the link to the original question: [Differenza tra "di" e "da"](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5845/differenza-tra-di-e-da)

Stack Exchange mobile app for iOS v1.3.2 (latest version at the time of writing)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the question?  Thanks

Comment: @BrianNickel Here's the link: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5845/differenza-tra-di-e-da

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce. http://i.stack.imgur.com/KQQCW.jpg Is this still happening on your end?

Comment: @BrianNickel No it isn't. This happened when reviewing the edit right after it was submitted, i.e. when it was still pending; that should make a difference I guess, as if I remember you get to edit's details by other means than how you'd get to the post revisions' history, and in any case they should be two different menus regardless, am I right?

Comment: @BrianNickel Comparing the two screenshots again: indeed they are two different menus (at least apparently, just check the labeling: `Suggested edit - By kos` vs `Revision 3 - By kos`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

There was a bug in the app were when two posts were being compared, if the a field was missing it was being treated as blank.  That is, a suggested edit with no title field was being treated as if it had somehow deleted the title.

Now the app will correctly hide fields that were unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for fixing this and for making the iOS app experience always better!